# A proper name to represent residuals over std. of mean obs?

Tags: t-test, standard-deviation, residuals, terminology

I have to use the following metric to represent difference between prediction and observation, and I would appreciate if anyone can give it a better name? Intuitively, if the value of this metric is between +/- 2, we will say not too much difference between prediction and observation, which is like the t-value. Here is the equation:

```
metric to be named = (Predicted-observed)/(SEM of observed)
```

I know this equation looks like "standardized residual", but it is not exactly. Since the definition of "standardized residual" is "The standardized residual is the residual divided by its standard error".

Should I just call this "Scaled Residuals"? According to "A scaled residual is simply a raw residual divided by a scalar quantity that is not an estimate of the variance of the residual."[[1]](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_intromod_a0000000355.htm)